# Self-copying script in startup folder of Windows Start menu

Tags: windows, batch-file

The file `main.bat` is in the `Startup` directory of the Windows `Start Menu`. It launches `debug.exe`, then it reads an integer `variable` (i) from `iteration.txt` and creates another `(i).bat` in directory for automatically started programs and scripts. Next it increments `i+1` and re-writes its value into `iteration.txt`.

The script works properly as long as being executed by `cmd` or with a double click. But when it is executed after system restart, it launches `debug.exe` file, increments and overwrites integer value in `iteration.txt`, but doesn't create any `.bat` file.

`main.bat` contains:

```
@echo off
start "" "%UserProfile%\debug.exe"
SET "MY_PATH=%UserProfile%\iteration.txt"
SET /p VARIABLE=<"%MY_PATH%"
(echo @echo off & echo.start "" "%UserProfile%\debug.exe" & echo.exit /s) > %VARIABLE%.bat
set /A NEW=%VARIABLE% + 1
echo:%NEW%>"%MY_PATH%"
exit /s
```

How to get the batch file created as expected on execution from `Startup` folder?

Comment: Are you sure bat file is not created at all? Could it be it is created instead, but in another folder? I'm afraid because filename used by redirection has no path at all, so main folder could be different from the one you expect.

Comment: I've been trying to search whole computer with 1.bat and 2.bat, but it didn't find anything.

Comment: The variable `%UserProfile%` is only available when you are logged in as a certain user; at system start-up there is no user context. By the way, there is no `exit /S`; did you mean `exit /B` instead?

Comment: The script that calls debug.exe which is in %UserProfile% is starting properly, so I assume the variable is set at the moment of execution.

Comment: On top of that, the variable in iteration.txt which is also in %UserProfile% is correctly incremented and overwritten.

Comment: @keevee, are you really running the exact commands you have posted into your question in your real world batch file? or have you made unnecessary changes, in the incorrect assumption that telling the truth would somehow invade your privacy, _(even though you've given no indication by your user name, or profile information who your are, and where you are employed or located)_. I ask because I do not understand what you're trying to do. Upon startup, if your code worked, you'd create a new batch file in StartUp, however, the previous batch files would still exist and run there too!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When the list of applications in `%APPDATA%\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\Startup` are launched as the user logs in, they're launched in the context of the Shell, inheriting it's working directory.  Generally, that means they'll be launched with `%SystemRoot%\System32` as their working directory.  Obviously, any shell links (.lnk files) have their own "Start In" directory set that the shell uses as the working directory to launch things.

All of this said, if you are literally placing a .cmd file in the Startup folder, when it's executed, the command interpreter will inherit the shell's default path of `C:\Windows\System32`, and this line:

```
(echo @echo off & echo.start "" "%UserProfile%\debug.exe" & echo.exit /s) > %VARIABLE%.bat
```

Will attempt to create a file in the System32 directory.  By default, that directory can't be written from the context of a normal user session, so the line will fail with an access denied error, and the batch file will continue on with the next line to run.

To fix this, you'll either need to explicitly change to a directory using `cd`, or explicitly output the file to a directory by including the directory after the `>` redirection symbol.  Probably the easist path is to add a line like

```
cd /d "%~dp0"
```

To the top of your batch file, causing it to set the working directory and current drive to whatever directory the batch file is in.